# Java: how to reverse the order of every N elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration, reverse

I have an input text file of thousands of lines of words, where I would like write to the output file, where I reverse the order of every 10 lines. I have iterated over the entire text file, and stored it in an `ArrayList<String> array` and I am now trying to figure out how I can reverse the order of every 10 lines in the entire ArrayList.

so for example the output should be like this: Line : 10, 9, 8, 7 ...... 1, 20, 19, 18, 17.....11, 30, 29, 28, 27.....21 and so on until I have done this for the entire text file (Stored in the ArrayList). Below is the portion of code I have been using to try and reverse the lines as stated.

```
   for(int i = array.size()-1; i >= array.size()-10; i--){ 
     array.add(array.get(i));
   }

   for (String text : array) {
            w.println(text);
        }

 }
```

What I have so far, reads and reverses only the last 10 lines of the input file and writes it to the output file. I have been having trouble figuring out a way to iteratively achieve this type of pattern throughout the entire data set, making sure that I do not hit an index out of bounds error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple streaming approach. This is basically the current solution applied *every* ten lines instead of once at the end.

1. Read ten lines in.
2. Reverse these lines<sup>1</sup>.
3. Write the ten reversed lines out.
4. Repeat until the entire file is processed.

The only edge case is doing something appropriate at the end when the file isn't a multiple of 10 lines.

This same streaming approach can be used to create a *new* each-10 reversed list. It only 'becomes complicated' when trying to mutating the original list.

---

<sup>1</sup> Steps 2 and 3 can be combined by iterating the list of ten lines backward when writing to the output.

Comment: Ok, at this point my code is reading in the entire input file and then storing it in an ArrayList, and then I am trying to work with that. Are you suggesting that I instead read segments of the code (10 lines at a time), so read the first 10 lines, reverse these and add them, then read the next 10 lines and so on? I have attempted to do this before, but I don't have very much experience with reading text files, so I didn't know how to implement it. How would I be able to read only a portion of specified lines at a time rather than reading the entire input file at once?

Comment: @MastRofDsastR Yes; that is the approach I suggest. When using the loop to read in the file initially, just check to see how many lines have already been added to the list: eg. `while (lines.length() < 10 && (line = inp.readLine()) != null) { lines.add(line); }`. When 10 lines are read process the output and then clear the ArrayList of lines read (or create a new list). After the loop you will have `lines` containing *up to* 10 lines. If there are less than 10 lines the end of the file is reached.

Comment: (So keep run the loop, processing the lines, and if there are 10 lines read, loop the entire read..process code again.)

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

1. If it is already in memory, in an `ArrayList`, simply update that list.
2. If not already in memory, process 10 lines at a time.
   This allows infinitely large data to be processed without running out of memory.

Option 1.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
// code filling list

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 10) {
    int endOfBlock = Math.min(i + 10, list.size());
    for (int j = i, k = endOfBlock - 1; j < k; j++, k--) {
        String temp = list.get(j);
        list.set(j, list.get(k));
        list.set(k, temp);
    }
}
```

Option 2.

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile)),
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile))) {
    String[] buf = new String[10];
    int len = 0;
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        buf[len++] = line;
        if (len == 10) {
            while (len > 0)
                out.println(buf[--len]);
        }
    }
    while (len > 0)
        out.println(buf[--len]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    for (int i = 0, size = array.size(); i < size; i += 10)
        for (int from = i, to = Math.min(i + 10, size); from < to;)
            Collections.swap(array, from++, --to);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a secondary counter variable and an if statement to check for bounds, such as:

```
while(counter<array.size()+10)
    int counter = 9; //since index 9 is the 10th line
    for(int i=counter; i>counter-10; i--){
        if(i<array.size()){
            array.add(array.get(i));
        }
    }
    counter+=10;
}
for (String text : array){
        w.println(text);
}
```

My only concern here is that you appear to just continue adding to the existing array rather than reordering it or adding the elements to a new array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stream-based solution using the [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature:

```java
// [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
List<String> lines = IntStream.range(1, 22).mapToObj(Integer::toString).toList();

// [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,22,21]
List<String> output = list.stream()
        .gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(10))
        .flatMap(window -> window.reversed().stream())
        .toList();
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with the new built-in [`Gatherers.windowFixed`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowFixed(int)) gatherer to group the list into groupings of 10 items at a time.

## Walkthrough

1. Convert the `List<String>` to a `Stream<String>`.

   ```java
   // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
   lines.stream()
   ```
2. Gather the elements into windows with 10 elements (or fewer, if at the end of the stream).  This results in a `Stream<List<String>>`.

   ```java
   // [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],[21,22]]
   .gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(10))
   ```
3. Reverse each window, and then flatten it.  This converts back to `Stream<String>`.

   ```java
   // [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,22,21]
   .flatMap(window -> window.reversed().stream())
   ```
4. Convert the `Stream<String>` to a `List<String>`.

   ```java
   // [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,22,21]
   .toList()
   ```

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.

[`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherers.windowFixed`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html#windowFixed(int))

> Returns a Gatherer that gathers elements into windows -- encounter-ordered groups of elements -- of a fixed size. If the stream is empty then no window will be produced. The last window may contain fewer elements than the supplied window size.
>
> Example:
>
> ```java
> // will contain: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
> List<List<Integer>> windows =
>     Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).gather(Gatherers.windowFixed(3)).toList();
> ```